# Plot Multiindex dataframe with different colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a multiindex dataframe like this:
[image]

```
new_index,Device:,sensor1,sensor2,sensor3,sensor4,sensor5,sensor6,sensor7,sensor8,sensor9,r_sensor9,w_sensor9,sensor10,sensor10.1
0,sda,2.97,338.57,40.97,100.26,4908.0,3474.59,59.35,0.65,4.58,1.64,5.79,0.7,9.83
0,sdb,1.99,339.0,17.22,99.62,2147.62,3472.93,48.1,0.31,2.64,3.21,2.54,0.84,9.81
0,md1,0.0,0.0,36.41,432.68,3656.69,3458.26,15.17,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
0,md0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.01,0.01,14.27,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,sda,0.0,5.0,0.0,41.0,0.0,332.0,8.1,0.29,7.02,0.0,7.02,0.51,2.1
1,sdb,0.0,5.0,0.0,41.0,0.0,332.0,8.1,0.28,6.76,0.0,6.76,0.51,2.1
1,md1,0.0,0.0,0.0,40.0,0.0,320.0,8.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,md0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2,sda,0.0,391.0,0.0,36.0,0.0,3382.0,93.94,0.37,10.22,0.0,10.22,0.72,2.6
2,sdb,0.0,391.0,0.0,36.0,0.0,3382.0,93.94,0.42,11.53,0.0,11.53,0.78,2.8
```

I'm trying to plot all the sensors with subplot but I can't get a different color for each device:

```
df.plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, figsize=(20, 12), layout=(5, 5))
```

With that code I get one color for each sensor / plot:

[image]

I need one plot for each sensor but inside each plot, one color for each device.
I tried a lot of methods and nothing works, any help is welcome. thanks!

Comment: How will one answer this if you will not provide any sample dataframe?

Comment: The first image is the dataframe i'm using

Comment: I included a sample of the dataframe. thanks